# how to give time duration for animation

Tags: jquery

I need to add time duration for animation, this needs to be animate 5000 seconds.

Here is code that i have tried.

```
$('.arrow_down').on('click',function (){
 var div = $(".animate");
    div.animate({height: '300px', opacity: '0.4'}, "slow");
    div.animate({width: '300px', opacity: '0.8'}, "slow");
    div.animate({height: '100px', opacity: '0.4'}, "slow");
    div.animate({width: '100px', opacity: '0.8'}, "slow");
```

});

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8qfjzuut/1/)

how to animate this 5000 milliseconds continuously?

Comment: have you tried replacing "slow" with 5000?

Comment: i want a continious animation...!!!! :P

Comment: 5000 seconds ?? Did you mean 5000 milliseconds ? To set a duration, simply set div.animate({height: '300px', opacity: '0.4'}, duration); with duration in milliseconds

Comment: Yes, 5000 milliseconds..

Answer (score 1):

instead of "slow" change to 5000 like that

```
div.animate({width: '100px', opacity: '0.8'}, 5000);
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> Duration
>
> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower
>   animations, not faster ones. The default duration is 400 milliseconds.
>   The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of
>   200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively.